# Google Analytics Goal Funnel Visualization

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is the Google Analytics - Goal Funnel Visualization report - an actual funnel? Meaning - does every step show only page hits from users who hit the previous page? i.e - if the first step is /signup and the last (the goal) is /pay, will i see only payed users who signed up on the selected dates, or will users who hit /pay and not /signup also show on the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is **closed funnel** and the answer is No. The Goal Funnel Visualization report is not a closed funnel. It's possible for a user to enter the funnel at any step. This is represented with the red box below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a better way to create a closed funnel like this with GA?

Comment: Google Analytics 360 (the paid version of GA) offers custom funnel functionality which can be either open or closed. Other than that, the only way would be to fire an event on each stage of the funnel and then use the GA API to pull this data and construct your own funnel report.

Comment: I have events for each step but how would you go about doing this with the api - can you make sure that for each query you only get data for users from previous queries?

Comment: You would have to construct your API calls in a way to ensure that, for each stage, you only get users that completed the stage before. This is more involved and outside the scope of this specific question. If you're interested in doing this, I suggest you post a separate question.